Intertemporal elasticity of substitution for leisure with log utility
I am interesting in proving that the elasticity of substitution between leisure in two periods is equal to one for the following utility function:
$$U = \ln(c_1)+b\ln(1−l_1)+e^{−\rho}[\ln(c_2)+b\ln(1−l_2)]$$
where $\rho$ is the discount factor. How would I go about doing this?

What is the utility function? This depends critically upon that.

U=ln(c1)+bln(1−l1)+e−ρ[ln(c2)+bln(1−l2)],
where
ρ
is a discount rate

please note that e to the power negative raw is the discount factor
